# How to insert Asset Browser Object at 3D Cursor?

Tags: modeling, asset-browser

Really straightforward question: How do I insert an Asset Browser object exactly at my 3D Cursor?

[image]

Comment: Literally right after I post, I realised the solution. First bring the object into the viewport, then snap it to the 3D cursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bring the Asset into the scene, then snap it to the 3D Cursor

[image]

Comment: btw for anyone who is unfamiliar with the snapping menu I am using, I am using the MACHIN3Tools version of snapping

Comment: I would suggest you edit your answer so that everyone can reproduce it - there is a Blender inherent tool to snap an object to the 3D cursor.

Comment: I have considered doing this. However, since the asset browser is arguably a tool only used by knowledgeable blender people, whether the act of snapping is shown through blender's default system or MACHINE3 doesn't matter since regardless, they'll still understand that I've snapped. hope that makes sense